# Interior wall insulation for walk in closet

Tags: insulation

We have a walk in closet that's always very cold in winter and very hot in summer. Are there any insulation products out there that can be installed over drywall. Doesn't have to be very appealing but not too thick. Looking for something that can be placed over drywall so it would be the outer layer.

Comment: That is not very specific in terms of temperature, material, appeal and cost.  You can put on anything, a discarded piece of carpet, a sheet of bubble-wrap.  Literally anything will help.

Comment: I highly doubt an interior wall will benefit from insulation; if the closet is a vastly different temperature than the rest of the interior, odds are it's simply not ventilated, or it's actually against an exterior wall that's not well insulated.

Comment: It is correct about the closet being against an exterior wall and I do believe that wall (and possibly others) are not well insulated.

Answer (score 1):

Start with ripping the drywall off and fixing the insulation in the wall.

"Not too thick" can't provide much insulation. You can add however much thickness you're willing to give up in sheet foam over the studs before you apply new drywall over that, but if you leave whatever situation of uninsulated wall cavities behind it, you won't get much insulation value unless you go pretty thick, and then you need more drywall or something over it for fire purposes. Drywall is fairly inexpensive, and a closet where you're not too picky how it looks is a great place to practice finishing it.

Comment: Thank you for this. In your opinion, can blown in insulation through a small cavity between each stud achieve good results? Or does it make more sense to just remove the drywall, insulate and put new drywall in.

Comment: Depends if the wall was simply left uninsulated, (where it could/should work fine) or if there's something that's gone on in there resulting in it being effectively uninsulated, where results might vary considerably.